# FieldDoesNotExist: User_balances has no field named 'None' - ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models, manytomanyfield

I am having a difficulty with a ManyToManyField and cannot seem to figure out how to fix this.
When I access the ManyToManyField I get this error

Models

```
class AccountBalance(BaseModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, verbose_name=_('Account Owner'), on_delete=models.PROTECT, 
        limit_choices_to{'is_staff': False},
        help_text=_("""The owner of Account Balance."""))


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    balances = models.ManyToManyField(
        AccountBalance,
        verbose_name=_("Account Balances"),
        related_name="account_balances",
        help_text=_("Account balances held by user.")
    )
```

Accessing `User.balances or User.balances.all()` etc. returns this error

```
FieldDoesNotExist: User_balances has no field named 'None'
```

What am I doing wrong here. I need help. Cannot seem to find any assistance even going through other suggestions, returns same error

This is my Query

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
```

Then to access to ManyToManyField

`user.balances` returns same error
`user.balances.all()` also same error

Stack Trace

```
In [73]: james.balances                                                                                                                                                
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py in get_field(self, field_name)
    574             # field map.
--> 575             return self.fields_map[field_name]
    576         except KeyError:

KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

FieldDoesNotExist                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-1d8b9c8fac05> in <module>
----> 1 james.balances

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py in __get__(self, instance, cls)
    534             return self
    535 
--> 536         return self.related_manager_cls(instance)
    537 
    538     def _get_set_deprecation_msg_params(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py in __init__(self, instance)
    837             self.reverse = reverse
    838 
--> 839             self.source_field = self.through._meta.get_field(self.source_field_name)
    840             self.target_field = self.through._meta.get_field(self.target_field_name)
    841 

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py in get_field(self, field_name)
    575             return self.fields_map[field_name]
    576         except KeyError:
--> 577             raise FieldDoesNotExist("%s has no field named '%s'" % (self.object_name, field_name))
    578 
    579     def get_base_chain(self, model):

FieldDoesNotExist: User_balances has no field named 'None'
```

Comment: Add the _full_ stack trace of your error to the question.

Comment: User.balances? is that your query?

Comment: I have edited question

Comment: What version of Django do you use? This seems to be related to this [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24513) which is fixed.

Comment: My version 3.1.4

Comment: Have you makemigrations and migrate ?

Comment: I have done migrations and still same error @ShubhamAgrawal

Comment: Got the same error, am wondering where it comes from